# Is this a clean way to typeset equations with notes on the right?

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting, align

I am not sure if my following example is good for creating equations with notes of current mathematical operations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
    x \cdot 5 &= 5 && \lvert \; \div 5 \\
    x         &= 1
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Is this the correct way to define these type of equations? Is there any other package which does the same in a better way? How would you create this equation?

Comment: Side note: `align*` is already an outer mathmode environment, you should remove `\[ .. \]`.

Comment: Ahh, you're right. I always forget that. I changed it, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest `witharrows`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows*}
x \cdot 5 &= 5 \Arrow{division by 5}\\
x     &= 1
\end{DispWithArrows*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, looks very nice. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a short macro to make this easier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    
  \newcommand{\eqnote}[1]{&\small\text{\llap{#1}}}

  \begin{align*}
    x \cdot 5 &= 5  \eqnote{$\lvert \; \div 5$} \\
    x         &= 1  \eqnote{This equals one} \\
  \end{align*}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, you can use a `\tag*`:

```
  \begin{align*}
    x \cdot 5 &= 5  \tag*{\small $\lvert \; \div 5$} \\
    x         &= 1  \tag*{\small This equals one} \\
  \end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I never heard about the ```tag``` command, I will try it out.